# Wordpress get list of child categories with pagination

Tags: wordpress, pagination

Sorry for my poor english.
I have 9 child categories which i am displaying on parent category page with pagination. i set 5 categories per page. So for 9 categories it should be 2 pages.
like page/1, page/2.   But for me its continues to page 3, page 4 and so on.
How can i stop the pagination when there is no more categories.
https://iwmagazineme.com/category/guides/

Here is my code for parent-category.php

```
<?php 
            if (is_category()) {
            $this_category = get_category($cat);
            if (get_category_children($this_category->cat_ID) != "") {
            echo '<div class="guides-categories"><ul>';

            $catpage = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
            $catnum = 5;
            $offset = ($catnum * $catpage) - 5;

            $childcategories = get_categories(array(
           'orderby' => 'id',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'hide_empty' => '0',
            'number' => $catnum,
            'offset' => $offset,
            'child_of' => $this_category->cat_ID
            ));
            ?>

            <?php
            foreach($childcategories as $category) {
            ?>

            <div class="row nopadding-guides">
            <?php echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">';  ?>

                <div class="col-md-6 guides-item"> 
                    <?php $image = get_field('guide_feature_image', 'category_'.$category->term_id);
                    echo '<img src="' . $image['url'] . '" />'; 
                    ?>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 guides-item"> 
                    <h2> <?php echo $category->name; ?> </h2>
                    <h5>by <?php echo get_field('guide_writer_name', 'category_'.$category->term_id); ?> </h5>
                    <p style="/*height: 152px;overflow-y: auto;*/margin-bottom: 0px;line-height: 23px;">  <?php echo get_field('guide_description', 'category_'.$category->term_id); ?> </p>
                </div>
            <?php echo '</a>'; ?>   

            </div>


            <?php  } ?>

            <div class="guides-pagination">
                <div class="next-page"> <?php next_posts_link( 'Next', ''); ?> </div>
                <div class="previous-page"> <?php previous_posts_link( 'Previous', ''); ?> </div>
            </div>

            <?php echo '</ul></div>';
                }
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: You're missing 'paged' from $childcategories array.

Comment: Still it show next Next link.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the 'paged' and 'posts_per_page' from $childcategories array:

```html
<?php 
            if (is_category()) {
            $this_category = get_category($cat);
            if (get_category_children($this_category->cat_ID) != "") {
            echo '<div class="guides-categories"><ul>';

            $catpage = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
            $catnum = 5;
            $offset = ($catnum * $catpage) - 5;

            $childcategories = get_categories(array(
           'orderby' => 'id',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'hide_empty' => '0',
            'number' => $catnum,
            'offset' => $offset,
            'child_of' => $this_category->cat_ID,
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'paged' => $catpage
            ));
            ?>

            <?php
            foreach($childcategories as $category) {
            ?>

            <div class="row nopadding-guides">
            <?php echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">';  ?>

                <div class="col-md-6 guides-item"> 
                    <?php $image = get_field('guide_feature_image', 'category_'.$category->term_id);
                    echo '<img src="' . $image['url'] . '" />'; 
                    ?>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 guides-item"> 
                    <h2> <?php echo $category->name; ?> </h2>
                    <h5>by <?php echo get_field('guide_writer_name', 'category_'.$category->term_id); ?> </h5>
                    <p style="/*height: 152px;overflow-y: auto;*/margin-bottom: 0px;line-height: 23px;">  <?php echo get_field('guide_description', 'category_'.$category->term_id); ?> </p>
                </div>
            <?php echo '</a>'; ?>   

            </div>


            <?php  } ?>

            <div class="guides-pagination">
                <div class="next-page"> <?php next_posts_link( 'Next', ''); ?> </div>
                <div class="previous-page"> <?php previous_posts_link( 'Previous', ''); ?> </div>
            </div>

            <?php echo '</ul></div>';
                }
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: Remove hide_empty from your array and tell me what is showed on the front.

Comment: removed but still showing untill 3rd page. https://iwmagazineme.com/category/guides/

Comment: It looks like there is your problem. You have posts in there. On the third and fourth page.

Comment: yes for each subcategory i have many posts. when i add the posts i select both parent category and child also. should i select only child ?